# AWS SES Interface Endpoint and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I'm trying to get one of my lambda functions to send an email using AWS SES.

I'm using boto3 and python, the code I have works locally on my machine but when run in lambda it just times out after 3 seconds, I'm convinced it's to do with my security group rules or connecting my interface endpoint to my VPC. My lambda function security groups have full SES access. I have 2 subnets and have created the endpoint with both selected. I feel like somewhere in the routing tables or the inbound rules I need to connect the endpoints so lambda knows where to send the email to but I cannot find the settings or instructions anywhere.

When I set up my S3 endpoint I just created the endpoint added it to my route table and it just worked.

I've been googling for the last 6 hours and cannot find the correct setup instructions for creating an endpoint for com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.email-smtp and connecting it to a lambda function.

Any help would be much appreciated.